# ExtJS Record with auto id Property

Tags: javascript, extjs

i have following problem with my ExtJS 5.1.0 Store.
When i want to create a new empty model with `var m = new (store.model)();` and set Values with `record.set(values);` ( Which come from a `Ext.form.Panel`) the record has next to the normal `Id`, a second `id`. The Second one looks like that: `"AM.namespace.model.ServiceContract-2"`.

Is it able to prevent a auto generated id?

To Create I use:

```
onAddServiceContract: function (item) {
    this.__form = item.up('form');
    var values = this.__form.getValues();
    var store = this.getStore('ServiceContract');

    var record = new (store.model)();
    record.set('Id', 0000);
    record.set(values);
    record.phantom = true;
    var rec = store.add(record);
}
```

The Store is defined as:

```
Ext.define('AM.####.store.ServiceContract',{
extend: 'AM.####.data.Store',
requires: ['Ext.data.proxy.Direct'],
model: 'AM.####.model.ServiceContract',

remoteGroup: true,

autoLoad: true,
//buffered: true,
pageSize: 1000,
leadingBufferZone: 500,
trailingBufferZone: 500,
autoSync: true,

constructor: function (config) {
    config = Ext.apply({}, config);
    if (!config.proxy) {
        var proxy = {
            type: 'direct',
            reader: {
                idProperty: 'Id',
                rootProperty: 'data',
                type: 'json'
            },
            writer: {
                allowSingle: true,
                writeAllFields: false // Note: Changed in ExtJS 5 to be default false
            },
            api: {
                read: AM.####.ServiceContract.List,
                create: AM.####.ServiceContract.Create,
                update: AM.####.ServiceContract.BulkUpdate,
                destroy: AM.####.ServiceContract.BulkDelete
            }
        };
        config.proxy = proxy;
    }

    this.callParent([config]);
    this.proxy.on('exception', this.onProxyException, this);
}
```

});

[image]

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mod the `idProperty` of the `model` to some other name.

For instance:

```
Ext.define('App.model.rssSoaFeed_m', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    idProperty:'extIdProperty',//renaming the extjs id property
    fields: [
        { name: 'title', type: 'auto' },
        { name: 'id', type: 'auto' }, //my custom id property
    ],
    proxy:
        {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: '/someurl.service',
            extraParams: {
            },
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                root: 'query.results.item'
            }
        }
});
```

And here is more info in [sencha docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.Model-cfg-idProperty)

Also, please note from the docs

> the idProperty may be configured as null which will mean that no identifying field will be generated.